# what is faster query (select name .... or select top(1) name

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

what is faster query ?

```
select Name from Worker
```

or

```
select TOP(1) Name from Worker
```

I have 1,000,000 records

thank's in advance

Comment: seriously?  isn't this something you can just test yourself?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legit question, simple and to the point, I understood what he's asking for. Sure, it could have been formatted nicer, but come on, -2? I'm giving it a +1.

Comment: Can those leaving downvotes leave a comment to explain? This is a good question to have, especially if you have ORDER BY and DISTINCTS in there and are confused about performance.

Comment: Are you kidding?  The first one returns 1 million records and the second returns 1 record.

Comment: @Sean Bright, what happened to 'No question is too trivial or too "newbie"', from the SO FAQ?

Comment: @Hardwareguy: If he was inadvertantly doing a distinct or an order by, performance between 1 and 1,000,000 is almost negligible (aside from the rendering aspects of it).

Comment: I think the question would be more relevant in a query like SELECT * FROM table WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM worker)

Comment: @Hardwareguy: Sure, but which one will be faster? And always keep in mind, there is no question too trivial. ;-)

Comment: How I can measure query Time ?

Comment: @gold SET STATISTICS TIME ON gives cpu and elapsed time

Comment: @Rob Me too. I Give it a +1 :)

Answer (score 11):

If you don't have an ORDER BY or a DISTINCT, `SELECT TOP(1) Name FROM Worker` is faster.

The reason for this is that if you do happen to have an ORDER BY or a DISTINCT, the query has to go through the entire table to sort and filter out unwanted results. If it's a straight SELECT TOP, however, it can go to the first page, take the first row, and be done with it very quickly.

Comment: True.  Of course if you have 1,000,000 records then selecting top 1 will be faster no matter what.  An order by clause will just slow things down further and narrow the difference in speed a bit.

Comment: During execution the query might flow control because the client is unable to parse the result fast enough (consume the 1 mil. names result set). So even with ordering the TOP 1 *may* be faster, depending on how slow the client processing is.